# Multiple iterations on URL

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to break one of my "for" loop once it returns empty "link".

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

cats = ['house', 'apartment']
try:
    for cat in cats:
        pages = np.arange(1,500)
        for p in page:
            url ='https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/'+str(cat)+'/for-sale?countries=BE&page='+str(page)+'&orderBy=relevance'
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
            data = json.loads(soup.find('iw-search')[':results'])
            for d in data:
                link = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/{}'.format(d['id'])
                if link ==0:
                   break
                #etc
                
except:
    pass
```

Except it keeps iterating on page without ever iterating on "cat".

Is there a way I can break off from that nested loop ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: `link` is a string, so `link == 0` will never be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways.  You can add an "exit" flag.  Set exit to False before the first loop, and check it in the outer loops.  That's what this code does.

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

cats = ['house', 'apartment']
try:
    exit = False
    for cat in cats:
        pages = np.arange(1,500)
        for p in page:
            url ='https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/'+str(cat)+'/for-sale?countries=BE&page='+str(page)+'&orderBy=relevance'
            soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
            data = json.loads(soup.find('iw-search')[':results'])
            for d in data:
                link = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/{}'.format(d['id'])
                if link ==0:
                   exit = True
                   break
                #etc
            if exit: break
        if exit: break
                
except:
    pass
```

Arguably a better design is to put this all in a function so you can `return`:

```
import requests
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    

def process():
    cats = ['house', 'apartment']
    try:
        for cat in cats:
            pages = np.arange(1,500)
            for p in page:
                url ='https://www.immoweb.be/en/search/'+str(cat)+'/for-sale?countries=BE&page='+str(page)+'&orderBy=relevance'
                soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")
                data = json.loads(soup.find('iw-search')[':results'])
                for d in data:
                    link = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/{}'.format(d['id'])
                    if link ==0:
                       return
                    #etc                
    except:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure; just check the condition again when you leave the inner loop:

```
    for p in page:
        ...
        for d in data:
            link = 'https://www.immoweb.be/en/classified/{}'.format(d['id'])
            if link == 0:
               break
        if link == 0:
            break
```

It's a little ugly, but so are the other options.  You have nested conditional iteration loops.  It would be nice to have `for d in data while link != 0`, but few languages give us that complex loop control.  Multi-level breaks are also nice, on those few occasions when we need them.